# Woocommerce Sold Individually Redirect to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to use the following code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_sold_individually_found_in_cart', 'sold_one');

function sold_one() {
    if ($found_in_cart) {
    $url='/my.domain/cart';
    return $url;
}}
```

The idea was to have a product sold individually bypass the "error message" by directly redirecting you to the cart page. 
Now it does work technically, but the problem is that on the cart page it calculates the product price subtotal and adds it, which I do not want. I tried to change the quantity with this:

```
$this->cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['quantity'] = 0
```

But I don't think I am going the right way with this. Maybe someone can provide some advice.